# How to create navigation tabs or thumbnails as Firefox or Google chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to show the important links or services in my website as multiple thumbnails or tabs like what we see in Firefox or Google Chrome when we open it and they show us the latest opened websites.

I think there is a way to do that with CSS or JQuery. I googled about it but I could not be able to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I'm not quite sure what you're referring to RE. a web browser interface, here's a really simple implementation of jQuery powered tabs: http://jsfiddle.net/i_like_robots/cc324/